# WinRt C# Audio Library

Tags: c#, .net, audio, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am looking to develop an app in C# WinRt, but was wondering what libraries are available for playback and for complicated manipulation. I am looking for a free library that allows for an extensive list of audio formats to be played (for example mp3, wma, wav, ogg, etc.) and also to be analyzed. Thats pretty much the basic functionality I would need. But if I could get picky, a library that can convert audio files between the formats would be handy. Doing a google search I came across the Naudio library, but it was not so greatly compatible with WinRt.Thanks for any tips or advice on this.

Comment: Have you tried [Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/) ?

Comment: its mainly focused on video, I need something that has the sole purpose of audio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current alpha build of NAudio 1.7 (available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio)) does contain a Windows RT assembly and the [source code](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioWin8Demo/MainPageViewModel.cs) includes a simple demo of playback and recording as a Windows Store app. Since it uses Media Foundation, you'll be able  to play most of the file types you suggested (although ogg won't be supported out of the box), and you can construct your audio pipeline to access the audio as floating point samples for analysis.

Things that aren't currently supported are using the Media Foundation encoders to encode, and the various reader/writer classes need to be re-written to use the WinRT asynchronous streams and File I/O APIs instead of the regular .NET ones. Hopefully these features will be added to the library soon.

Comment: Install-Package : Could not install package 'NAudio 1.7-alpha06'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: that's strange. Alpha06 definitely does contain the Windows store dll, and I did test installing it. Have you got an up to date NuGet?